# How to populate my database using a JSON in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, database

I am trying to populate my database by parsing a JSON file and running a ruby script once that would create instances of my models and save them in my database.

Example Script:

```
require 'json'
require 'byebug'

file = File.read('players.json')
data_hash = JSON.parse(file)
data_hash_size = data_hash['Name'].size

data_hash.each_with_index do |i|
  @student = student.new
  @student.name = data_hash['Name'][i]
  @student.college_year = data_hash['Cl.'][i]
  @student.save!
end
```

My question is, where do I put such a script in my app and how do I connect it to the models I want to create instances of to populate the database? Currently, it's giving me an error: undefined local variable or method student for main:Object (NameError). I even tried `require 'app/models/student.rb'` and it still doesn't work. I currently have the script placed in the app home directory (with the README file and such). Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try placing your script file in Rail's `script` directory. Once you place it there add this to the top of your file:

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby

require '../config/environment'

.......script code.....
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. If I want to run this script only once to populate the database, do I just run it through rails console (or Heroku console when I deploy it) or is there a more elegant way?